# I have a Pandas code error, but the solution is uncleared

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie to Python, and I have been dooing this Pandas code for reading malware IP addresses, this is the code and below is the error.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import subprocess
import pyjq
import pandas as pd

# Initializes the variables for the directories
HomeDir = "Users/kiya/Downloads/"
ScriptDir = HomeDir + "pan-python-0.12.0 2"
ResultDir = HomeDir + "techscroll/"

# Create the dates
ToDay = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
# checkDATE = (date.today() - timedelta(1)).strfttime('%Y%m%d')
ResultFile = "Test"
CheckDATE = "Test"
NOWDATE = "TEST"

# Run the panafpi
subprocess.check_output('python ' + ScriptDir + '/bin/panafapi.py -K secretkey --samples -j -r "{\"query\":{\"operator\":\"all\",\"children\":[{\"field\":\"alias.ip_address\",\"operator\":\"contains\",\"value\":\"' + ResultFile + '\"},{\"operator\":\"any\",\"children\":[{\"field\":\"sample.update_date\",\"operator\":\"is in the range\",\"value\":[\"' + CheckDATE + 'T00:00:00\",\"$' + NOWDATE + 'T23:59:59\"]},{\"field\":\"sample.create_date\",\"operator\":\"is in the range\",\"value\":[\"' + CheckDATE + 'T00:00:00\",\"' + NOWDATE + 'T23:59:59\"]},{\"operator\":\"any\",\"children\":[{\"field\":\"sample.malware\",\"operator\":\"is\",\"value\":1},{\"field\":\"sample.malware\",\"operator\":\"is\",\"value\":4}]}]}]},\"scope\":\"global\",\"size\":1,\"from\":0,\"sort\":{\"create_date\":{\"order\":\"desc\"}}}" > ' + ResultDir + 'srciplist-' + ToDay + '.json', shell=True)

# Using pyjq to filter
filteredResultData = pyjq.all('.hits[]._source | .create_date + "," + .sha256')

# Save the JSON file to comma-separated file
pd.to_csv(ResultDir + "/srciplist-" + ToDay + ".csv", sep=",")
```

error:

```
/bin/sh: Users/kiya/Downloads/techscroll/srciplist-20180125.json: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mani/Downloads/tester (1).py", line 22, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output('python ' + ScriptDir + '/bin/panafapi.py -K secretkey --samples -j -r "{\"query\":{\"operator\":\"all\",\"children\":[{\"field\":\"alias.ip_address\",\"operator\":\"contains\",\"value\":\"' + ResultFile + '\"},{\"operator\":\"any\",\"children\":[{\"field\":\"sample.update_date\",\"operator\":\"is in the range\",\"value\":[\"' + CheckDATE + 'T00:00:00\",\"$' + NOWDATE + 'T23:59:59\"]},{\"field\":\"sample.create_date\",\"operator\":\"is in the range\",\"value\":[\"' + CheckDATE + 'T00:00:00\",\"' + NOWDATE + 'T23:59:59\"]},{\"operator\":\"any\",\"children\":[{\"field\":\"sample.malware\",\"operator\":\"is\",\"value\":1},{\"field\":\"sample.malware\",\"operator\":\"is\",\"value\":4}]}]}]},\"scope\":\"global\",\"size\":1,\"from\":0,\"sort\":{\"create_date\":{\"order\":\"desc\"}}}" > ' + ResultDir + 'srciplist-' + ToDay + '.json', shell=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'python Users/kiya/Downloads/pan-python-0.12.0 2/bin/panafapi.py -K secret key --samples -j -r "{"query":{"operator":"all","children":[{"field":"alias.ip_address","operator":"contains","value":"Test"},{"operator":"any","children":[{"field":"sample.update_date","operator":"is in the range","value":["TestT00:00:00","$TESTT23:59:59"]},{"field":"sample.create_date","operator":"is in the range","value":["TestT00:00:00","TESTT23:59:59"]},{"operator":"any","children":[{"field":"sample.malware","operator":"is","value":1},{"field":"sample.malware","operator":"is","value":4}]}]}]},"scope":"global","size":1,"from":0,"sort":{"create_date":{"order":"desc"}}}" > Users/kiya/Downloads/techscroll/srciplist-20180125.json' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: Does this file exist? `Users/kiya/Downloads/techscroll/srciplist-20180125.json: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Evan do I need to download the json file as well?

Comment: Well, your program is looking for that file, and can't find it. Look at the `subprocess.check_output` line of your code's error message: it creates that file name, can't find the file, and generates an error.